# Failure to connect to MySQL server from SQL Server Migration Assistant

Tags: mysql, sql-server-migration-assi

I have SQL Server 2017 Developer installed. I want to use the SQL Server Migration Assistant for MySQL to migrate a MySQL database into SQL Server. But I can't get the migration assistant to connect to the MySQL server. First of all, using MySQL Workbench I can connect to the server with no problem through this dialog box;

[MySQL Workbench connection dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciuvV.png)

Using the same service, (or server) name, port and user entered into the migration assistant dialog box for connecting to the MySQL server;

[SQL Server Migration Assistant connection to MySQL Server dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqgaA.png)

I get an error message saying,

Cconnection to MySQL failed. ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.2(w) Driver]Unknown MySQL server host 'Mysql@127.0.0.1' (0)

I've tried selecting both the ANSI and unicode ODBC drivers, version 5.2 and 5.3. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Yes. That works. I'd like to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove "Mysql@" from the connection string. This isn't a necessary part of the hostname when connecting through SSMA.